# Storing variables between Jersey REST request / responses

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey

I'm a Jersey / REST newbie and am trying to write a simple web service. The issue I have is the storage of data between requests.

Servlets can access sessions but I didn't believe Jersey / REST allows this.

I am currently writing this service so that an Android app will make RESTful requests to Tomcat.

Now I am not sure yet of the type of request these will be: should they be URLs with parameters, or simply an XML string? The type of data to be transmitted from the app will include addresses of RSS feeds and keywords and sundry metadata.

The XML responses from the server will again consist of RSS feed addresses, keywords, frequencies of the keywords and other metadata.

The idea at the moment is to use JAXB on both app and server to make up and break down the XML into Java objects.

JSON or GSON are not available alternatives here.

But what about storing data between requests? Is it enough to store all the relevant variables in XML if XML forms the request and response actions, where each request will have an ID number referring to the server's database.

Or is it better to use the session context for servlets via REST?

Apologies if the above sounds vague. I am a Jersey / REST newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST webservices are based on the HTTP protocol which is a stateless protocol.
In my opinion, saving state in your webservice is not a good idea.
You should use cookies to store user data.

Comment: But am I storing state between requests though? I would have everything wrapped up in XML sent to / from client / server per request / response. And can Android store cookies?

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to store between requests?

Comment: The question has been amended slightly to give more information.

Answer (score 5):

While as has been said it is generally recommended your WS calls to be stateless, Jersey does rely on Servlet, so you can inject the HttpServletRequest and get the session from there:

```
@GET
public String getMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    HttpSession session= req.getSession(true);
    ...
```

You can then configure your web server session storage to memory, cookie, cache, db, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS services can either be singletons or per-request objects. A singleton
means that one and only one Java object services HTTP requests. Per-request means
that a Java object is created to process each incoming request and is thrown away at
the end of that request. Per-request also implies statelessness, as no service state is held
between requests.

Comment: I intend that per request, a new Java object would be created when a request is received by the server. All details of the request would be persisted to the database, and the response would contain a unique identifer (stored in the XML of the response) serving as a session id of sorts. As I understand Jersey, it would emulate the servlet aspect to handle multiple requests.